# Variables of required type not provided despited their validity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, graphql, react-apollo

I'm getting a GraphQL error I can't seem to pinpoint the source of.

> Variable "$title" of required type "String!" was not provided.
>   Variable "$body" of required type "String!" was not provided.
>   Variable "$price" of required type "Int!" was not provided.

The error message is simple. There are three required variables for this mutation and the error shows that none of the type are provided even though they're clearly provided.  The confusing part is the same mutation using the GraphQL Playground works perfectly fine. Using other mutations in the front end also work as they should.  This tells me this isn't an issue with the resolver nor the server in general.

My GraphQL for the mutation looks as follows:

```
export const CREATE_POST_MUTATION = gql`
    mutation CreatePost($title: String!, $body: String!, $price: Int!) {
        createPost(data: {
            title: $title, body: $body, price: $price
            }
        ){
            id
            title
        }
    }
`
```

I'm using Apollo's React Hook:

```js
    const [createPost, { data, loading }] = useMutation(CREATE_POST_MUTATION, {
        onCompleted: data => {
            setCompleted({
                data,
            })
            setModal(true)
        },
        onError: data => {
            setCompleted({
                isOpen: true,
                error: true,
            })
        },
    })
```

The submit handler for the form:

```js
   const submitHandler = async (value) => {
        const { title, price, description } = value
        try {
            await createPost({
                variables: {
                    data: {
                        title,
                        body: description,
                        price: Number(price),
                    }
                }
            })
        } catch(err) {
            throw new Error(err)
        }
    }
```

Console logging `title`, `price`, `description` show the state so they are properly passed to `createPost`. Even when I assign values directly to `createPost`'s variables without passing in the states, the same errors show.  This tells me these errors have nothing to do with the form.

I'm using Formik and Yup for the form in a child component, but even when I strip away everything down to the bare bone to just `TextInput`, the same error messages show:

The GraphQL schema on the server side:

```
type Mutation {
    createPost(data: CreatePostInput!): Post!
}

input CreateUserInput {
    title: String!
    body: String!
    price: Int!
}
```

When I console log the corresponding mutation resolver on the server's side, the request and arguments don't even reach there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you're passing in your variables inside `data`, your graphql isn't expecting them inside `data`.  So change

```
await createPost({
  variables: {
    data: {
      title,
      body: description,
      price: Number(price),
    }
  }
})
```

to

```
await createPost({
  variables: {
    title,
    body: description,
    price: Number(price),
  }
})
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could also just keep your `createPost` call as is and change your query so that it only has a single variable (`$data`) with the appropriate type.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. But, I'm confused because my GraphQL and Schema both have `data`

Comment: Your mutation defines the variables with `mutation CreatePost($title: String!, $body: String!, $price: Int!)` and then inside the mutation, passes them in inside an object with `data`.  But you have to pass the variables in in the exact same way you define them.

Answer (score 1):

I spent my 8 hours for solving this issue.

My answer is based on `useMutation` from `@apollo/react-hooks` module.

1. make user that you have same `(createPost or CreatePost)` .And dont forget to put `$` sign infront of data.

> ```
> export const CREATE_POST_MUTATION = gql`
>     mutation createPost($data: CreateUserInput!) {
>         createPost(data: $data){
>             id
>             title
>         }
>     }
> ```

2. Make sure you pass the all your mutation data inside `data` object.

> ```
> await createPost({   variables: {
>    data: {
>    title,
>    body: description,
>    price: Number(price),
>       }}})
> ```

3. make sure you have current input type and same `createPost` function defined in server side code.

For for information please follow [official docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#usemutation)

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same challenge, i got frustrated and just couldn't figure out what i was doing wrong. But finally i was able to fix it. From your code, the things i discovered you did wrong are (i) the type of should be CreateUserInput!  and (ii) createPost after mutation should match exactly, take not of the letter-case. This should fix your bug.

```
     export const CREATE_POST_MUTATION = gql`
        mutation createPost(data: CreateUserInput!) {
            createPost(data: $data){
                id
                title
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to miss: a trailing comma in your query variables can lead to this error:
[image: subtle error message]

Hovering over that error, it will show `Expected String, but found '}'.`

Subtle, and the error message didn't lead me in the right direction.